# Add custom div to selected/clicked on text with Quill?

Tags: quill

In this [demo](https://codepen.io/quill/pen/KzZqZx) there's a dropdown with the options "Heading 1", "Heading 2" and "Normal". I'm looking for a way to customize that with my own options (or adding a new button instead of dropdowns) using div classes. For example, I want to add a new option called "myThing" and it turns this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

into this:

```
<div class="myThing">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by extending the block blot. As shown in the [this section](https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment/#blockquote-and-headers) of the Quilljs guides. Just extend the block blot, and set your tag and class name. Example:

```js
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

class MyThing extends Block {}
MyThing.blotName = 'my-thing';
MyThing.className = 'my-thing';
MyThing.tagName = 'div';

Quill.register(MyThing);

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['my-thing']
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.ql-toolbar .ql-my-thing {
  width: 60px !important;
}
.ql-toolbar .ql-my-thing:before {
  content: 'My Thing';
}
.my-thing {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.js"></script>

<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
```

Comment: custom div and classes both are getting removed when binding it as HTML to the quill editor. Any workaround for this?