# Add more buttons after editor is loaded?

Tags: quill

Building a bit on the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625666/add-custom-div-to-selected-clicked-on-text-with-quill), I would like to know if it's possible to add more buttons to the editor **after** it is loaded/constructed. I have one custom button like this:

```
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

class MyThing extends Block {}
MyThing.blotName = 'my-thing';
MyThing.className = 'my-thing';
MyThing.tagName = 'div';

Quill.register(MyThing);

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['my-thing']
    ]
  }
});
```

The user should be able to add their own buttons into this editor. There's a separate textfield somewhere, where they can write down the name of the button and then have it added as a new button to the editor after submitting it.

Is that possible? I want to be able to do something similair to this (doesn't work, obviously):

```
var newButton = $('#newButtonName').val();
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

class NewButton extends Block {}
NewButton.blotName = newButton;
NewButton.className = newButton;
NewButton.tagName = 'div';

Quill.register(NewButton);

quill.modules.toolbar.push(newButton);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is posted as an issue in the official github repo of quill. [See here](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1891). Apparently, modifying the toolbar dynamically is not officially supported. A workaround for this is also mentioned there but i couldn't understand how it worked. 

I was able to create another workaround though not a good one. Basically i just modify the options and reinitialize the editor. It seems to work and entered text is preserved when the editor is reinitialized. 
Here is the code: https://codepen.io/nik648/pen/VQMxQj. Note: To test it, enter `my-thing-2` into the input field and click add. Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to work, but I was really confused why it only worked with "my-thing-2", until I realized there's no styling generated for the new buttons, so they appear but simply don't have any text because of the missing styling. Surely, I can just update the stylesheet with javascript to include new css classes for these buttons? Gonna have to try that out when I have time, but for now, this seems to be my solution. Many thanks!