# How to create a button that adds a string with HTML tags and classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

Based on this [link](https://codepen.io/alexkrolick/pen/gmroPj), I tried to add a new button, which allows me to have a string inserted at cursor position. It works so far, however I had to change this line:

```
this.quill.insertText(cursorPosition, "★");
```

to:

```
this.quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(cursorPosition, '<i>★</i>');
```

as I wanted to be able to paste HTML tag with the string.

Now, in the next step, I want to add a class with the HTML tag:

```
this.quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(cursorPosition, '<i class="my-icon">★</i>');
```

However, whenever I click the button now, the class is just completely discarded. In fact, instead of the tag *i*, I get the tag *em*, which works for what I want to do (italics), but it's still annoying.

How can I make sure the tags and class stay the same when I click the button? All I want to do is to click a button and have a little string enclosed in a span with a class to appear in the editor. How can I achieve this?

Comment: even if you edit the html directly in the devtools, jquill will repair and replace `i` with `em`. This means you cannot have your own html inside the editor as it standardizes all the html input. So even though want to achieve this, it can't work

Comment: The bounty is about to expire, please check the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update: 24-Apr-18**

So it took a lot of time to actually figure this out and get it working. It is possible to do this by create your own `Blot` and overriding the `italic` blot

```
let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');

class Icon extends Inline {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    if (value) {
      console.log(value)
      node.setAttribute('class', value);
    }
    return node;
  }

  static formats(domNode) {
    console.log(domNode)
    return domNode.getAttribute("class");
  }

  format(name, value) {
    console.log(name, value)
    if (name !== this.statics.blotName || !value) return super.format(name, value);
    if (value){
      this.domNode.setAttribute('class', value);
    }
  }
}
Icon.blotName = 'icon';
Icon.tagName = 'span';
Quill.register(Icon);

var BackgroundClass = Quill.import('attributors/class/background');
var ColorClass = Quill.import('attributors/class/color');
var SizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
Quill.register(BackgroundClass, true);
Quill.register(ColorClass, true);
Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);


var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'
});


var customButton = document.querySelector('#custom-button');
customButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  quill.insertText(quill.getSelection().index, "★\n", 'icon', 'fa fa-icon fa-icon-green');
});
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tarunlalwani/pen/WJwMyg) for the same

[image: Working]

**Original Answer**

`QuillJS` is rich text editor and not a HTML WYSIWYG editor. So you cannot get your own custom html inside the same

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyEjrQ

In the above code pen, click source, try your code and click source again

**Source view**

[image: Source view]

**Source view -> UI View -> Source view**

[image: Converted source view]

If you try to remove the clipboard matchers, then you will nearly break the rich text functionality.

So either you leave this requirement or you pick a different editor for your job. Some threads you should look at

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1856

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1733

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1657#issuecomment-325737074

Comment: Something doesn't add up for me. You're able to add custom buttons to the editor. You can, for example, add a custom button that puts the line your cursor is currently on into a div with the name of your own choosing, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665916/add-more-buttons-after-editor-is-loaded). Is it _really_ not possible to do the same with an inline element like a span? (obviously only for selected text, like how the bold button works) There _has_ to be something like this... or is quilljs really incapable of it?

Comment: Not really... check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/quill/pen/gLBYam). Select some text and change the font. Inspect it. You will see a span was added to change the font, using a class. Can't I do something like that myself? A custom button that adds a span with a class like that?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you'd be a real saviour if you figure this out for me. I'm too dumb to figure it out myself and I'm kinda losing my patience. :D

Answer (score 3):

As API says "The snippet is interpreted by Clipboard matchers, which may not produce the exactly input HTML." [link](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml) As I have tested it removes id, class or whatever attribute you add.

You should edit the clipboard.js file to obtain this: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/modules/clipboard.js#L97

**Other option** is include an image, in this case it fits and shows it, for example:

```
this.quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(cursorPosition, "<img src=\"http://vchaspik.ua/sites/default/files/krug.png\"><i>★</i>", "silent");
```

Comment: Isn't there another way? I don't really have the ability to change those files and I'd rather not touch them anyway. I just want the span to be added with the class when I click the button, it doesn't need to be using dangeriouslyPasteHTML. There has to be something more fitting for this purpose. On a side note... what's the point of the *other option*? That doesn't help at all, what am I supposed to do with an image when I want a span with a class to be added?

Comment: Thats what I've found @noClue, sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
function insertStar() {
  const cursorPosition = this.quill.getSelection().index;
  this.quill.insertText(cursorPosition, "★");

  var bufferText = $(".ql-editor").html().replace(/<em class="my-icon">/g, "").replace(/<\/em>/g, "");

  var tmpOut = bufferText.replace(/★/g, "<em class='my-icon'>★</em>");

  $(".ql-editor").html(tmpOut);

  this.quill.setSelection(cursorPosition + 1);
}
```